# Unique values in column but omit zeros and blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column `B` I've got the list of values of which some occur multiple times.
What I am trying to achieve is to list unique values of such list in column `E`. For cell `E3` I use the array formula like this:

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$20,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$2:E2, $B$3:$B$20), 1)),"")}`

but I'm not sure how to add another layer to this formula which would drop all blank cells from `B`. Now the formula treat blanks as the zero value and returns zero in the first row.

Comment: Are there zero's in your list too, or do you only need to omit blanks?

Comment: There only blanks in column `B`. But the alternative formula to exclude zero or any other chosen value in the result would be also neat :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this into **`D3`** and copy down to the cells below to get a unique list of  non-blanks value that are in `B3:B20`:

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF($D$2:D2, $B$3:$B$20)=0)*($B$3:$B$20<>"")), $B$3:$B$20)
```

You can just enter this normally since it is **not** an array formula.

It you copy the formula into more cells than there are unique values, you're get `#N/A` errors.  You can avoid this by using `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((COUNTIF($D$2:D2,$B$3:$B$20)=0)*($B$3:$B$20<>"")),$B$3:$B$20),"")
```

<sub>([Source](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/10/how-to-automatically-create-a-unique-list-and-remove-blanks/))</sub>